# Remove Transparency From Glyph.Data in SpeedButtons

Tags: delphi, forms

I have an old app (Delphi 5) which I want to give it some changes.

I have set a Glyph.Data for a speedbutton, but some colors are transparent and in some places I see small white dots on my image, I do not want to set transparency for the image, How to remove it (transparency)?

Any help is really appreciated. 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transparency is a color that is not drawn.
You just have to change the image or set another color as the transparent one.

**From Delphi 6 Help**

> Transparent color
>
> Use the Transparent color drop-down to
>   specify which color is used to create
>   a mask for drawing the image
>   transparently. The default transparent
>   color is the color of the bitmap's
>   left-most pixel in the bottom line.
>   You can also change the transparent
>   color by clicking directly on a pixel
>   in the selected image.
>
> When an image has a transparent color,
>   any pixels in the image of that color
>   are not rendered in that color, but
>   instead appear transparent, allowing
>   whatever is behind the image to show
>   through.
>
> If the image is an icon, Transparent
>   color appears grayed and the
>   transparent color is set to clNone.
>   This is because icons are already
>   masked.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set [TSpeedButton.Transparent](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Buttons_TSpeedButton_Transparent.html) to False.

Comment: @ Lars Truijens It did not worked, It gave error! Here is the code:                 object SpeedButton4: TSpeedButton
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 438
    Height = 420
    Glyph.Data = {Image}

Comment: @Lars I believe Majid is trying to do this development using a resource editor and modifying the .dfm file based on recent questions. It would appear that Majid does not have a Delphi compiler. The problems started when Majid added a comctl32 v6 manifest, again presumably using a resource editor.

Comment: I have Delphi compiler, just lost resources of my project and want to set some small changes on it.

Comment: Really I can not build it, it is for year 2002, I made it with the help of my friend. And now after years I want to make some changes in its interface...So The only thing that I have in my hands is RCData which ca edited by res editor, do any help in this case is really appreciated :)

Comment: Ok, I have extracted my form in dfm format, after opening it in Delphi, there is no option for removing transparency from glyph bitmao in speedbutton, Transparent = False just get speedbutton transparent. So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, Delphi thinks the transparent color is the color of most left - bottom pixel of this image. So If I set a color which is not used in my image in the most left-bottom of my image, then Delphi only will make that small pixel transparent and other parts of my image will be OK without transparency, So this post is completed by myself :))